# How do you define and initialize a 3 dimensional Array using IBM Cplex OPL script

Tags: arrays, cplex, opl

On the ibm website http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21573358
they defined and initialized a 2- dimensional array  in the Main Opl script as below

```
main {

    var var_2d = new Array(3);
       for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
         var_2d[i] = new Array(3);
         for(var j=0; j<3; j++) {
           var_2d[i][j] = 1;
         }
       }

}
```

I am trying to define and initialize a 3 dimensional array but the array I defined and initialized gives me " undefined as the result"
my code is below:

```
a =2
 m=3;
 n= 2;

 Range A= 1..2;
 Range M = 1..3;
 Range N = 1..2;

// declare 3 dimensional array in the Main script

main{
var var_var_temp2 = new Array (thisOplModel.a+thisOplModel.m+thisOplModel.n) ; 

// initialize the  3 dimensional array
     for( var r in thisOplModel.A){
         var_var_temp2[r] = new Array(thisOplModel.m);
            for( var i in thisOplModel.M) {
                 var_var_temp2[r][i] = new Array(thisOplModel.n);
                    for ( var j in thisOplModel.N) {
                     var_var_temp2[r][i][j]= 1.0;    
                        }
              }  
          }  
// code to print the value stored in temp2[r][i][j]

for (r in thisOplModel.A) {
                 for (i in thisOplModel.M){ 
                      for (i in thisOplModel.N) {  
                                writeln( var_var_temp2[r][i][j]);                                           
              }                 
                 }       
                      } 

}
```

The value I got was a

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

As is, your example has syntax errors in CPLEX Optimization Studio 12.8.

If I change the top part to the following:

```
int a = 2;
int m = 3;
int n = 2;

range A = 1..2;
range M = 1..3;
range N = 1..2;
```

That is, include types and replace "Range" with "range", then it seems to run fine. The output is as we would expect:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: thanks rkersh i made a typo error in the question.  my  "range" was written as range in the program and still the result was  underfined underfined etc

Comment: I made a typo error in my question. My code was actually written with range and not Range. The results still gives me underfined

Comment: What version of CPLEX are you using? How are you running the example? With 12.8, using the IDE, your example does not even run due to the syntax errors.

Comment: i use cplex 12.8.   could you help me with correct syntax for declaring and initializing a 3 dimensional array on the IDE?

Comment: Did you also fix the declaration of `a`, `m`, and `n` as I suggested? After the changes above, the example is working for me, so I'm not sure what is going on with your setup. Can you successfully run other OPL examples? What operating system are you using?